# How can I see localstorage input datas?( in Chrome )

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I practice a simple todolist by using localstorage.

As you can see in this screenshot, it works as I intended.

[image]

But is there anyway to check those inputs that I typed in?

I checked this link [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored)

It said in Chrome I should follow this path

%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\

And I followed this path(*there is nothing but only leveldb folder in Local Storage folder*)

[image]

Now I have no idea what represents my inputs.

Also what is that .idb file? Is it some sort of database files? I searched it on Google and it gave very vague answer.

Sorry English is not my main language so my writings would be bad for reading.

Comment: Can't you just `var aValue = localStorage.getItem(keyName);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a levelDB file. Related: [Local Storage with Chrome 61](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325138/local-storage-with-chrome-61)

However, what Chrome does with these files should not be of your interest. It can change over time.

You should only interface with the [Browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and not care about the files on the disk.

---

To see what is stored in localStorage for the current domain do this:

`console.table(localStorage)`

... or as mentioned, use `Chrome DevTools => Application => Local Storage`

---

To get or set a value use:

`const obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo'))`

`localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify({ bar: 'zulu' }))`

Comment: Thank you! Better have to use those or if I really want to get DB based file, I think I should use something else to work with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alternatively to localStorage there is also indexedDb

Comment: "You should only interface with the Browser API and not care about the files on the disk."

There are way more use cases than just using the Browser API.

Answer (score 0):

**View Local Storage With Chrome DevTools.** Open DevTools using **right-click on the browser and inspect element**. Then you will see many options like Elements , console, sources, etc.**Click on Application** after that on the **left side menu you will see local storage, Session Storage**, and many more options.

**Right Click on Browser  -->  Click on inspect or inspect Element -->  Click on Application --> Local Storage(on left side menu)**

[image]